# Are the super fast fighters in movies edited to be fast or are they actually fast?

Tags: entertainment, speed

I'm wondering if those fighters in movies (like Daniel LaRusso) are actually fighting super fast and executing flying split kicks or if the movements are edited to be super fast before the movie comes out.

Comment: most of the movies its Both, actors do fast training and with CGI special effects